# Can't call controller method, breaks because of the %20s in link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC5 Application and I'm working on basic CRUD functions. I can create and it all writes neat into the Db. But when I want to 'edit' or 'delete', it seems to mess up because it adds many %20 into the URL. But it works, if I manually trim them down to the id. Then I can call the method and the appropriate view is shown. What I am missing here?
Must I trim the input, or add something into the Web.Config file...?

The link looks like this:

```
Delete/1%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20
```

Controller Method:

```
public ActionResult Delete(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Test test = db.Tests.Find(id);
            if (test == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(test);
        }

        // POST: /Test/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(string id)
        {
            Test test = db.Tests.Find(id);
            db.Tests.Remove(test);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Comment: Yea I would say just trim it somewhere. Either when your pulling it out of database or when putting it in the link

Comment: Seems like your frontend is appending some spaces to the id. Have you tried to trim the id before posting? Send "1" instead of "1       ...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The %20 is an HTTP-safe encoding of the space character, so your actual ID here is ten characters - the "1" character followed by nine spaces, that then get encoded.

Where are these spaces coming from? My guess is that, in your database, you've declared your ID field as a fixed-length field with a length of 10 (i.e., CHAR(10) rather than VARCHAR(10)). You could either change your database to use a variable-length string field instead, or as you say you could call Trim() on the ID when writing out your links.